# How the "Customizable Options" works while adding the product in magento 2

Tags: product, custom-options, backend, adminform, magento2.2.2

I need to know the where the below section is loads in magento 2, Especially in dropdown. While clicking "Drop down " in Option Type, It loads the below section,Actually what are the responsible files to load dropdown

[image]

Comment: have you tried enabling Template / Block hints in the admin? `Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes`

Comment: yes i have tried, but did not get the correct path